# Does " I will go at x o'clock," imply I will arrive at said time, or does it imply I will have left for the bar at said time

Tags: verbs, time, ambiguity

For example, If I were to say, "I will go to the bar at two o'clock," does it imply I will arrive at said time, or does it imply I will have left for the bar at said time.

Comment: Anyone who receives this message is likely to understand that you will be at the bar at 14.00.  The context of the statement might lead to a different understanding.

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably use this when the time it takes to get to the bar is quite short, or you don't care too much about accuracy.

If you need to be unambiguous about whether you are referring to a leaving time or an arrival time you could use

> I'll leave for the bar at...

> I'll get to the bar at...

> I'll arrive (at the bar) at...

Comment: Does the verb to go imply anything when coupled with a time?

Comment: In context, yes. Out of context it probably means "leave".